# Qmake and passing $ORIGIN to linker option -rpath

Tags: qmake

I would like to use the -rpath linker option to set the .so search path. I'd like it to search `[app_path]/../lib`. I've tried add this to my qmake `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN/../lib/
```

But qmake links my project this way:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath=RIGIN/../lib/ -Wl,-O1 -o myoutput main.o [...]
```

How can I escape the `$ORIGIN`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want `$ORIGIN` to be (properly) evaluated while building you can simply add this to your `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_RPATHDIR += $ORIGIN/../mylibs
```

Comment: Interesting. Is this a new option?

Comment: I discovered it here while I was trying to make `QMAKE_RPATH` work: [QTBUG-8110](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-8110). According to this link `QMAKE_RPATH` and `QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH` don't work anymore. `QMAKE_RPATHDIR` works for me at least with Qt 4.8.4 and Qt 4.8.5.

Comment: It is defined here: [qmake Variable Reference](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-rpathdir)

Comment: I've tried it in Qt 5.3-5.5 and it's doesn't work correctly.

Comment: doesn't work on qt 5.5. Parker's "QMAKE_LFLAGS += .." answer is correct

Comment: @VitorPy, my answer to your question is obviously outdated and your own answer is the most upvoted one. Please go ahead and make your answer the accepted one :)

Comment: @Aurelien My own answer is from 5 years ago, I have no idea if it still works.. I'm unsure of what to do.

Answer (score 22):

I found [here](http://codea-dev.blogspot.com/2010/12/qmake-rpath-and-evil-origin.html) a way to properly escape it:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += '-Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN/../mylibs\''
```

Comment: I just thought I'd mention that I had to add `-z origin` to get things working for me. So all together, that's `QMAKE_LFLAGS += '-Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN/../lib\',-z,origin'`.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I could not get QMAKE_RPATHDIR to work, and there is chatter on the 'net indicating that indeed QMAKE_RPATHDIR does not work.

Answer (score 9):

This is a really old question, but for people getting here through a search: the methods described in the old answers are not needed anymore. Modern Qt versions (5.9 in my case), allow you to just use this:

```
QMAKE_RPATHDIR += lib
```

This will add the needed entries (including `$ORIGIN` and `-Wl,-z,origin` where needed) automatically to the makefile, as long as you're using a relative directory. Meaning that `lib` will produce the needed "origin" entries, while something like `/lib` will not. Any relative directory you add to `QMAKE_RPATHDIR` will be made relative to `$ORIGIN` automatically.

Comment: A true lifesaver. Works with Qmake version 3.0 of Qt 5.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

DOLLAR=$

QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath=$${DOLLAR}$${DOLLAR}ORIGIN/../myLibs